# Настройка сети

Tags: сеть

Привет, помогите настроить сеть :(. Локалку протянул, хаб установил, IP адреса написал, модем настроил, а интернет работать отказываетса. Хотя компы друг друга видят. Вопрос, как можно подсоеденить 11 компов к одному главному, чтоб интернет был на всех 11-ти компьютерах. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

На Самом Главном Компьютере наверняка есть подключение к инету. В свойствах этого подключения к инету на вкладке "Дополнительно" есть "Общий доступ к подключению" где нужно выбрать требуемое подключение по локальной сети (если их несколько). В свойствах Подключения по локальной сети на других ПК в качестве шлюза указать ip-адрес Самого Главного Компьюетера. DNS - либо провайдера, либо гугловский 8.8.8.8 (или оба можно указать). Это если вы хотите  чтобы весь трафик шел через один ПК (например, для сбора статистики, просмотра загруженности канала и.т.д.). Если у вас интернет через АДСЛ-модем либо другой роутер (например, sapido rb-1632), то при включении его в LAN достаточно указать в качестве шлюза его ip-адрес.Рекомендации приведены для windows. Если у вас другая ОС - уточните.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое - купить , установить и настроить раутер (маршрутизатор). Ежели есть желание сделать из компа маршрутизатор, то необходимо для него две сетевые карты. А далее зависит от Ос , что на нем стоит. Если Linux - то настраиваем маскарадинг (NAT) в iptables. Если Винды - то устанавливаем мост между сетевыми подключениями.

Comment: Сетевой мост? Для объединения локальной сети с интернетом? Вы шутите?

Comment: Поставьте для подключения в интернет "Разрешить другим пользователям сети использовать подключение к Интернет данного компьютера". Наверно правильнее будет так. По современному. Раньше было "Соединение типа мост"(для win2000).

Comment: Это все-таки "немного" разные вещи. Сетевой мост объединяет две сети. Любой ПК из сети 1 доступен любому ПК из сети 2 и наоборот. "Разрешить другим пользователям сети..." - это уже NAT-трансляция, получить доступ к любому ПК из сети 1 к любому ПК за NAT'ом из сети 2 просто так не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Если провайдер предоставляет вам динамический ip, то вам лишь нужно поставить в настройках соединения "автоматичекски DHCP" и на последующие машины просто прокинуть витые пары (ip в этом случае должны прописаться автоматом) при статическом подключении на свитче задайте адреса как угодно, главное чтобы главный кабель стоял в ячейке под номером один и был прописан как 192.168.0.1, последующие по нарастанию 192.168.0.2, 3, 4, 5 итд (не забываем указать DNS) Во многом все зависит от оборудования и ОС: [строим локальную сеть](http://forum.freesoft.ru/index.php?showtopic=253) | [сеть своими руками](http://www.computerbild.ru/hard/1043519/).

Comment: Вы уверены в своих словах? Могу вас заверить, вы по меньшей мере в половине своего ответа допустили ошибку.---------К внутренней сети (та, что за модемом) DHCP от провайдера вообще не имеет никакого отношения.---------В какой последовательности подключать кабеля не играет никакой роли.---------Свитч - это такая тупая коробка которая только лишь исполняет простенький алгоритм сопоставляя МАС-адреса и номера своих портов. Он не конфигурируется.

Comment: Ну если в половине ответа есть смысл... Я в данном наборе букв вообще смысла не уловил. Первая ссылка еще ничего, а вторую можно заменить одним предложением "Локальные сети существуют"

Comment: @sergarcada, небольшой смысл в упрощении объяснения во второй части ответа все же просматривается, не хотел быть столь уж категоричным.